# What is the most correct asp.net page lifecycle event to change a label's text?

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

Joined a company that use Asp.Net, a tech that I had never worked with before. I have a very simple task to do which is to change a label's text depending on a value that is included in the logged in user's session.

I considered **Init**, **Page Load** and **PreRender** and ended up placing my code in the **PreRender** event and got a comment in a code review from the main code reviewer saying "this does not belong here, go and investigate the page lifecycle to figure out why"

According to the docs:

- **Init** should be used to "initialize control properties" (which seems to be about right for this case).
- **Page Load** should be used to "set properties in controls and to establish DB connections".
- **PreRender** should be used to "make the final changes to the page or its controls"

I can't see an obvious event that should be used instead of the others. I wrote above that Asp.Net is new to me so I may be missing something.

Which event should be used in this particular case, and in general, to change properties of controls?

Comment: In page load... You very, very rarely have to use Init and PreRender (even with dynamic controls).

Comment: @VDWWD, why do you say that? examining these guys's code base, they do use Init and PreRender a lot, especially Init

Comment: Can you also post an example of code they put in PreRender? (I've never done this before and am curious what it's used for...)